# Images and backgrounds of react project not showing on vercel

Tags: reactjs, image, deployment, vercel

I deployed my react project from my local machine to vercel, it was successful but no images could display. I have my image folder in my root directory

I don't know how to fix the issue, I can't find solutions on YouTube or elsewhere

Comment: can u upload your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.